# Digital Ocean build stuck

Tags: python, django, digital-ocean

I want to run a Python Django app on Digital Ocean and use [this](https://docs.digitalocean.com/developer-center/deploy-a-django-app-on-app-platform/#step-5-deploying-your-static-files) tutorial.

It worked in the spring, but now the build stops (stuck and stops after 60 minutes with a timeout) in the app upload stage.

Any ideas?

[image]

**Update**
Finally, after 4h, Digital Ocean posts an error in the building platform:
[image]